# Financial term for low point in my forecast

Tags: banking

I regularly do my financial planning for household finances by putting in expected income, regular monthly payments and projected extra payments into my financial software. After that I go through and find the date that has the lowest balance and use that to plan my irregular expenses for the month. For instance, if my low balance is on the 12th of the month with $2000 in the bank, then I know that I can reasonably only spend up to $2000 without over drafting the account until the 13th.

Is there a financial term for this projected low balance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Lowest Projected Balance** seems to be the most widely used, particularly in relation to Mortgage Escrow Accounts.

This [Quicken Help Page](https://www.quicken.com/how-project-balances-and-cash-flow)<sup>**1**</sup> talks about the process of producing *projected balances* – as you do in your question – but while it talks about identifying *negative* projected balances (i.e. when you will have run out of money) it doesn't specifically refer to a "lowest" balance.

Of the two "obvious" phrases for the minimum balance, "*minimum projected balance*" and "*lowest projected balance*", the latter appears to have more hits according to a well-known web search engine. Most of these are in relation to Mortgage Escrow Accounts. For instance:

- This PDF of ["Escrow Definitions" by the Farmers National Bank](https://www.farmersnb.com/ContentDocumentHandler.ashx?documentId=39820)<sup>**1**</sup> contains:

  > **Lowest Projected Balance**
  >
  > This amount is calculated by taking your beginning escrow balance, adding the projected monthly escrow payments, and subtracting the projected tax and insurance payments when they are due.
- [Abbreviations.com](https://www.abbreviations.com/term/1757560) gives:

  > **Lowest Projected Balance**
  >
  > This term is used in relation to Mortgage Escrow Account Balances. Based on projected payments into and out of the Escrow account, during an analysis of the Escrow account, a forecast/projection of the lowest balance is determined and used to decide if additional payments will be needed to cover all bills the account is used to pay, or if a surplus is expected and a refund should be issued to the account owner.

Although those usages are in relation to a Mortgage Escrow Account, I see no reason the phrase shouldn't apply to projected balances of any account.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> Both found through random web-search: I have no affiliation with either organisation.